# Bootstrap col 3 dropdown menu doesn't show full width child menu

Tags: css, menu, nav

i try create a mega menu with css. Actually it works well outside my nav. I design my nav bar with 3 col. on the middle i put dropdown menu but sub menu extends up to col-lg-6 but i want to extend it full with.

```css
ul {
      list-style: none;
      }
      
      li {
      display: inline-block;
      }
      
      a {
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: grey;
      }
      
      a:hover {
      background: #efefef;
      }
      
      
      
      li .sub {
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      background:#e5e5e5;
      }
      
      li:hover .sub {
     display: block;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-8 logo">
                    LOGO
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 visible-lg hidden-xs">
                    
                    <ul>
                       <li>
                          <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                          <div class="sub">
                             <div style="width:35%; height:200px; float:left;">
                                LOGO
                             </div>
                             <div style="width:65%; height:200px; float:left;">
                                SUB MENU WITH SOME CONTENT
                             </div>
                             <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                          </div>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 hidden-xs">
                    <form id="search" name="search" method="get" action="search.php">
                        <input class="search" type="text" name="tag" id="tag" placeholder="Arama Yap" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following will help you :

```
li .sub {
   display: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: fixed; /* changed to fixed from absolute */
   left: 0;
   right: 0; /* added to occupy the full width*/
   background:#e5e5e5;
}
```

You can see the demo here: http://www.bootply.com/xnqkM3x4wd